# Problem with initial SCRAM to Authenticate Clients in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I follow the instructions for the initial mongo setup exactly. I was able to successfully install the base. I'm creating a basic admin user to further set up secure access to the database.

At the point of the manual for the Ubuntu 20.04 operating system, everything just freezes for me.

More from the guide:

1. Re-start the MongoDB instance with access control

Shut down the mongod instance. Using  mongosh, issue the following command:

`db.adminCommand( { shutdown: 1 } )`

2. Exit mongosh
3. Start the mongodwith access control enabled.

If you start the mongod from the command line, add the `--auth` command line option:

`mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb`

If you start the  mongod using a configuration file, add the security.authorization configuration file setting:

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

I successfully run the command from point 1 and close mongosh.

Next, I enter the command in the console from point 3 and everything freezes. The following information is displayed in the console, but the command itself is not completed to the end.

Information in the console:

```
root@p510728:~# mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:10:49.819+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:10:49.822+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:10:49.823+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:10:49.827+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:10:49.827+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:10:49.827+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:10:49.827+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:10:49.828+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":556,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"p510728.kvmvps"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:10:49.828+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.2","gitVersion":"94fb7dfc8b974f1f5343e7ea394d0d9deedba50e","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:10:49.828+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
...
Further, the output to the console just starts to break, the command does not complete
```

At the same time, everything seems to freeze and I can get access again only when the current process is stopped. However, if I go further through the guide and try to log in with the current password, I get the following message:

```
root@p510728:~# mongosh --port 27017  --authenticationDatabase "admin" -u "Admin" -p
Enter password: ********
Current Mongosh Log ID: 6349c4b717e8f5fa346256a6
Connecting to:          mongodb://<credentials>@127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&authSource=admin&appName=mongosh+1.6.0
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

What am I doing wrong? How to access mongo? I did not touch the configuration file, did not change it ip, port and security parameters. All steps so far have been successful. I tried restarting the server but that didn't help.

UPD

I tried restarting the server with the following command `sudo systemctl restart  mongod` and got the following output:

```
root@p510728:~# sudo systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-10-14 23:36:52 MSK; 1s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 854 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
   Main PID: 854 (code=exited, status=14)

Oct 14 23:36:51 p510728.kvmvps systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Oct 14 23:36:52 p510728.kvmvps systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Oct 14 23:36:52 p510728.kvmvps systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0):

This list of commands solved my problem, I don’t know why, but obviously something in the configuration processes is going wrong (

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock    
sudo service mongod restart
```

Additionally I manually changed my config file as mentioned in the manual